# How to mass upsert on Tarantool?

Tags: sql, tarantool

In MySQL I can do something like this:

```
-- post_id-user_id is unique pair
INSERT INTO userviews(post_id, user_id, view_count) 
VALUES(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,1,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
view_count = view_count + 1;
```

Or in PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO userviews(post_id, user_id, view_count)
VALUES(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,1,1)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET view_count = view_count + 1;
```

How to do this kind of thing in Tarantool? (Currently I'm using Tarantool's library to upsert in a loop):

```
import "github.com/tarantool/go-tarantool"
type AX []interface{}
...
for ... {
   conn.Upsert(`userviews`, tuple, AX{AX{`+`,viewCountColumn, 1}})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that `upsert()` works differently than MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Unlike MySQL, it checks for uniqueness *only* the primary key and ignores all other secondary *unique* indices. Not sure if this is your case, but if you need to replicate the exact behavior of MySQL and update the entry regardless of whether there is a duplicate on the primary key or any secondary unique index, the only decent way I found is to write a Lua function that first tries to insert the tuple and if the operation failed with error code 3 (Duplicate key exists in the unique index), it does the update.

> (Don't know for sure, but maybe you can also use Tarantool/SQL, which is available in tarantool since version 2.)

Unfortunately, it does not yet support UPSERT: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/5732

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem you aim to solve is about performance. The naive variant (perform an operation, wait for a response, continue with the next operation) would give about (1 / network RTT) RPS at max: it is about 1000 RPS for 1ms RTT.

There are the following options:

1. Use async operations (go-tarantool supports them) and wait for a batch rather than for each operation. (You can even sending one batch while waiting for the previous one.)
2. Define a Lua function, which accepts a batch of requests and returns a batch of responses (if you need each response, of course).
3. (Don't know for sure, but maybe you can also use Tarantool/SQL, which is available in tarantool since version 2.)

You can also use 'eval' operation without having a function on the server side, but it requires 'execute' permission on 'universe' and so usually discouraged (except for testing and experimenting purposes).